# react empty PDF when using .html from jspdf

Tags: reactjs, jspdf, html-to-pdf

I'm trying to create a pdf from my react component. I use renderToHTML to make it a string and use .html that act as .fromHTML() but when I click the button to trigger the generatePDF function it only download pdf with blank content. How to fix this ?

my component code:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Container, Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap'

const PDF = () => {
  return (
    <Container fluid style={{width: "21cm", height: "29,7cm", margin:"",}}>
        <h1 >UD-SUPERJAYA</h1>
        <p className="fontBold">Invoice #0178832</p>
        <hr />

        <Row>
            <Col lg={6}>
                <p className="fontBold">Invoiced to</p>
                <p>slow fast Mahendra</p>
                <p>Jalan Kalimantan No 29, jawa Kota, 1</p>
                <p>Indonesia</p>
            </Col>

            <Col lg={6} className="text-end">
                <p className="fontBold">Pay to</p>
                <p>PT sea sea</p> <br />

                <p>NPWP: 94090239402940290</p>
                <p>No PKP: PGM-432423/dad.1.1/321/KR0239/32131312</p>
                <p>Tgl Pengukuhan: 17 Desember 2013</p>

                <br/>
                <p>Alamat:</p>
                <p>Jalan Kalimantan No 29, USKota, Jawa</p>
                <p>Telp: 0822 3323 3333</p>

            </Col>
        </Row>
    </Container>
  )
}

export default PDF
```

My main app code :

```
    const generatePDF = () => {
        const stringify = renderToString (<PDF /> ) 
        var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm');
        doc.html(stringify);
        doc.save('Invoice.pdf')
    }

 return (
    <>
      <Row>
         <Col lg={12} className="text-end fontMedium">
            <Button onClick={generatePDF} className="invoicebutton">Submit</Button>
         </Col>
      </Row>
   </>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, the doc.html() methods is not finished yet, if you are calling the doc.save() method.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).